# How to resolve local domains to localhost on macOS

Tags: dns, localhost

I know there are other similar questions but I am not satisfied with the answers.

I would like to be able to define a local domain such as `.localhost`, or `.local` or whatever and make all the subdomains to be resolved to localhost (127.0.0.1).

I want it to work offline, so I don't want to rely on something such as localtest.me.

I would like to be able to do it without extra software such as a DNS. But I'm ok with it if it is absolutely necessary.

[EDIT] I don't want to edit my /etc/hosts file manually every time I need a new host.

I know I was able to do it previously with `resolv.conf` but I've seen I shouldn't use this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the hosts by ip on /etc/hosts

First thing resolver would ask is this file, after it it goes to your dns local provider.

This link could help u to edit the file, structurate and samples:

https://help.nexcess.net/en_US/miscellaneous/how-to-find-the-hosts-file-on-my-mac

regards

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it, but editing `/etc/hosts` is not an option. I can't configure something like `127.0.0.1   *.local`. I want all possible subdomains to be redirected automatically.

Comment: On that case, i dont think you wolud have an easy option. I dont have much imagination, i would aproach this situation by setting up a DNS service on a rpy, or vm, or even in the local machine, would set the 1st resolver to him and set the above resolver on him to elsewhere requests. On his zones  you can add everithing u want.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options already posted on [ServerFault (20 answers to choose from)](https://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain), with and without 3rd party software (I use some of them on my Linux systems).

If you don't like any of them you really need to be more specific in your question.